# Global variable changed in function not effective

Tags: powershell, global-variables

I just tried this code:

```
$number = 2

Function Convert-Foo {
    $number = 3
}
Convert-Foo
$number
```

I expected that function `Convert-Foo` would change `$number` to 3, but it is still 2.

Why isn't the global variable `$number` changed to 3 by the function?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, I'm afraid PowerShell isn't designed that way. You have to think in `scopes`, for more information on this topic please read the PowerShell help [about scopes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes?view=powershell-6#short-description) or type `Get-Help about_scopes` in your PowerShell ISE/Console.

The short answer is that if you want to change a variable that is in the global scope, you should address the global scope:

```
$number = 2

Function Convert-Foo {
    $global:number = 3
}
Convert-Foo
$number
```

All variables created inside a `Function` are not visible outside of the function, unless you explicitly defined them as `Script` or `Global`. It's best practice to save the **result** of a function in another variable, so you can use it in the script scope:

```
$number = 5
    
Function Convert-Foo {
   # do manipulations in the function
   # and return the new value
   $number * 10
}

$result = Convert-Foo
    
# Now you can use the value outside the function:
"The result of the function is '$result'"
```