# How to substitute repeated script statements in multiple functions by a predefined script block or other mean?

Tags: powershell

I have multiple functions. By the end of the function they all need to go through exactly the same couple of lines of code, doing some logistic work. How can I define these couple of lines of code into a script block outside these functions and be able to use for all functions, either global reference or passed in as an argument(less preferred)?  These lines of code will involve both global and local variables. The ideal is whenever I need to update the logistic work content, I can update it in one place, like script block definition, instead of using a function, which seems overkill for a few lines of codes. Thanks.

```
function A {
    ...
    $var1 = $global:x + 1
    Write-Host var1 value is $var1
}

function B {
    ...
    $var1 = $global:x + 1
    Write-Host var1 value is $var1
}

$global:x = 0

A

B
```

Comment: Small functions that do one very small well defined thing is actually a design pattern that is often aspired to. If I understand what you want then I would actually prefer to have a two line function that I called.

Comment: Keep in mind that modifying `Global` variables in a function isn't best practice. [It makes it very hard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30590972/global-variable-changed-in-function-not-effective/30591470#30591470) for someone reading your script to see what is actually happening in or outside the scope.

Comment: Pass the variables as parameters to your functions. Or just write a function. I know which one I'd prefer.